# C++ Errror: "FL/Fl_xyz_Button.H: No such file or directory" in Fltk?

Tags: c++, fltk

I'm new to C++ and Fltk. Guys this code is working fine:

```cpp
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Button.H>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Fl_Window *window = new Fl_Window(800, 400);
    Fl_Box *box = new Fl_Box(20,40,300,100,"Hello, World!");
    box->box(FL_NO_BOX);
    box->labeltype(FL_SHADOW_LABEL);
    Fl_Button *GG = new Fl_Button(150,90,40,30,"GG");
    GG->type(FL_NORMAL_BUTTON);

    window->end();
    window->show(argc, argv);
    return Fl::run();
}
```

but when I try this code (when using `Fl_xyz_Button.H`):

```cpp
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>
#include <FL/Fl_xyz_Button.H>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Fl_Window *window = new Fl_Window(800, 400);
    Fl_Box *box = new Fl_Box(20,40,300,100,"Hello, World!");
    box->box(FL_NO_BOX);
    box->labelfont(FL_BOLD+FL_ITALIC);
    box->labelsize(36);
    box->labelcolor(FL_WHITE);
    box->labeltype(FL_SHADOW_LABEL);
    Fl_xyz_Button *GG = new Fl_xyz_Button(150,90,40,30,"GG");
    GG->type(FL_NORMAL_BUTTON);

    window->end();
    window->show(argc, argv);
    return Fl::run();
}
```

it's show me error:

```cpp
"FL/Fl_xyz_Button.H: No such file or directory"
```

and I see in `/usr/local/include/FL` doesn't have `Fl_xyz_Button.H` ??
How Can I fix it ? or download `Fl_xyz_Button.H` and put it inside `/usr/local/include/FL` folder?

I searched in that and there is no resault?

I use Xubutu(.deb) on Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xyz` is just a placeholder name for one of the possible button types, check the [documentation](https://www.fltk.org/documentation.php/doc-1.1/common.html) for available types and the corresponding header:

- Fl_Button - A standard push button.
- Fl_Check_Button - A button with a check box.
- Fl_Light_Button - A push button with a light.
- Fl_Repeat_Button - A push button that repeats when held.
- Fl_Return_Button - A push button that is activated by the Enter key.
- Fl_Round_Button - A button with a radio circle.